# Older short story foreshadowing the internet about a boy who was the only person who could not connect to a central computer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to track down a short story, that I think was by Heinlein (?), about a boy who was the only person who could not connect to a central computer like everyone else and had to learn to read books like a barbarian. At the end, the computer breaks down and he is the only person who knows how to do anything.

There was a tv adaptation in the late 90s…

Comment: The TV 'adaptation' could be The Outer Limits episode *[Stream of Consciousness](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667957/)*, but that wasn't an adaptation it was an original work by David Shore

Comment: I think it's Asimov, not Heinlein, but can't help further than that.

Comment: Definitely not Heinlein.

Comment: @AntonSherwood - Asimov wrote a few different stories on this general theme; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Feeling_of_Power

Comment: _The_ classic Asimov story about being unable to use computer (tape) education and having to read books to learn is "[Profession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profession_(novella))"

Comment: I think the outer limits is the tv adaptation I was thinking of. Not exactly the same but tv never is, it is very very similar. I recall reading it quite a few years earlier. Thus far I have made a mess of my library and fallen down a few dozen rabbit holes. I didn’t realize there was an Alfred Bester story in science fiction hall of fame…damn my adhd…